# Binning Percent Ranges with Labels Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe called "Trump2020." This column houses percentages of the votes he received. Example values in this column: 34.66%, 51.00%, 75.00%, etc. I want to bin this column with 3 labels: **lose** which would be anything less than 50%, so 0% to 49%, **win** would be 50% to 64% and **win by landslide** which would be 65% to 1.

How can I make the three categories to the percentage groups?

Comment: please provide a text (or dataframe) sample of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), as long as your values are numerical (ordered).

```py
    df["Trump2020_bin"] = pd.cut(
        df["Trump2020"],
        [0, 50, 65, 100],
        labels=["lose", "win", "landslide"],
    )
```